# Verifying unmarshalled entries from List( Jaxb)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a 4 XML files having a structure as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Registry>
    <Insitutions>
        <Insitiution>
            <name>A</name>
            <location>B</location>
        </Insitiution>
        <Insitiution>
            <name>C</name>
            <location>D</location>
        </Insitiution>
        <Insitiution>
            <name>E</name>
            <location>F</location>
        </Insitiution>
    </Insitutions>
</Registry>
```

I have written the classes for individual XML tags, and have unmarshalled them using jaxb.
I unmarshall all the files and store all the entries in a list as follows:

```
  private static List<String> loadBaseNodesets() throws JAXBException {
        log.info("Loading nodesets");
        Registry xmlentries = null;
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        List<Registry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> privateBaseNodeSets= new ArrayList<>();
        File dir = new File("XMLFiles");
        if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
            FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    return file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xml");
                }
            };
        log.info("iterating through all files");
        File [] files = dir.listFiles(filter);
        if (files != null) {                    
                for (int i =0;i <1;i++) {   
                    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Registry.class);
                    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                    xmlentries = (Registry) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(files[i]);
                    privateBaseNodeSets.add(xmlentries.toString());
                    log.info(files[i].getName()+" NodeSet loaded");
                    entries.add(xmlentries);            
                }
            }
        
        }       
        log.info("Nodeset loading complete");
    return privateBaseNodeSets;
  }
```

I need to put all the xmlentries to a list of string.

Now from the main program, I would like to check if I can get the same format of the XML entries.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    log.info("Started local test main");
    List<String> baseNodesets = loadBaseNodesets();
    ListIterator<String> litr = baseNodesets.listIterator();
    while (litr.hasNext()) {
        
        JAXBContext jaxbContext=JAXBContext.newInstance(Registry.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();#
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(, System.out);// DONT KNOW THE FIRST PARAMETER
        }
```

I am not able to get the first parameter here. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Did the answer help you? Were able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Ofcourse it did! sorry was a little held up. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but I am guessing you are trying to do something like this:

1. Read each file one by one and unmarshal and store in `entries` List.
2. Then loop over the `entries List` and marshal them one by one.
3. Store the converted XML into List

I stored 2 same XML files in a folder and tried to read it

XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Registry>
    <Insitutions>
        <Insitiution>
            <name>A</name>
            <location>B</location>
        </Insitiution>
        <Insitiution>
            <name>C</name>
            <location>D</location>
        </Insitiution>
        <Insitiution>
            <name>E</name>
            <location>F</location>
        </Insitiution>
    </Insitutions>
</Registry>
```

Root:

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "Registry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Insitutions")
    @XmlElement(name = "Insitiution")
    private List<Insitiution> Insitiution;
}
```

Insitiution:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Insitiution {
    private String name;
    private String location;
}
```

Marshalling (Main):

```
public class Marshalling {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, FactoryConfigurationError, IOException, SAXException {
        final File dir = new File("/Users/Downloads/test");
        final List<Root> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.newJAXB.Root.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final StringWriter singleXmlEvent = new StringWriter();
        final List<String> xmlOutput = new ArrayList<>();
        final Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (!file.isDirectory() && file.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
                //Storing all the files into entries List
                final DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
                final com.newJAXB.Root root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, com.newJAXB.Root.class).getValue();
                entries.add(root);
                System.out.println(root.toString());
            }
        }

        //Loop through each entry in entries and marshal it
        for (Root item : entries) {
            marshaller.marshal(item, singleXmlEvent);
            xmlOutput.add(singleXmlEvent.toString());
            // Clear the StringWriter for next event
            singleXmlEvent.getBuffer().setLength(0);
        }

        //Final all the XML
        System.out.println(xmlOutput);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Root(Insitiution=[Insitiution(name=A, location=B), Insitiution(name=C, location=D), Insitiution(name=E, location=F)])
Root(Insitiution=[Insitiution(name=A, location=B), Insitiution(name=C, location=D), Insitiution(name=E, location=F)])
[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Registry>
   <Insitutions>
      <Insitiution>
         <name>A</name>
         <location>B</location>
      </Insitiution>
      <Insitiution>
         <name>C</name>
         <location>D</location>
      </Insitiution>
      <Insitiution>
         <name>E</name>
         <location>F</location>
      </Insitiution>
   </Insitutions>
</Registry>
, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Registry>
   <Insitutions>
      <Insitiution>
         <name>A</name>
         <location>B</location>
      </Insitiution>
      <Insitiution>
         <name>C</name>
         <location>D</location>
      </Insitiution>
      <Insitiution>
         <name>E</name>
         <location>F</location>
      </Insitiution>
   </Insitutions>
</Registry>
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method [marshal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html#marshal-java.lang.Object-java.io.Writer-) need a java object to be transformed to XML as the first parameter.

This will transform your list of entries to a list of xml.

```
    final JAXBContext jaxbContext=JAXBContext.newInstance(Registry.class);
    final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    List<String> xmlEntries = entries.stream().map(entrie -> {
      OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      marshaller.marshal(entrie, os); <-- your object to transform to XML
      return os.toString();
    }.collect(Collectors.toList());
```